# failed to resolve glide, now 3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

Everything working fine before updating android studio 3.0.1, but after updating android studio I am stuck with

**Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018
Failed to resolve: glide
Open File
Folder /home/lalit/repositories/android/WaveDist/app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/debug
Folder /home/lalit/repositories/android/WaveDist/app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/release
3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause**

My gradle dependence

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.+'
    implementation 'com.github.wrdlbrnft:sorted-list-adapter:0.2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0'

}
```

App level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    ext.roomVersion = '1.0.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Please help me..

**EDIT**
I have added mavenCentral() which resolves "failed to resolve glide",
and now I am ended with this

```
Folder /home/lalit/repositories/android/WaveDist/app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/debug


Folder /home/lalit/repositories/android/WaveDist/app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/release


3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause
```

**Edit**

I am using dexMode, so I have removed that

```
 dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
```

and added `multiDexEnabled true` in default config, which removed my compile time error.

Now when I am trying to run application It displays long error...

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/lalit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/android.arch.lifecycle/common-java8/1.1.1/795d68cd761d093ccb235d1d91b8fd17c2ae25ff/common-java8-1.1.1.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/lalit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/android.arch.lifecycle/common-java8/1.1.1/795d68cd761d093ccb235d1d91b8fd17c2ae25ff/common-java8-1.1.1.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:327)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/lalit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/android.arch.lifecycle/common-java8/1.1.1/795d68cd761d093ccb235d1d91b8fd17c2ae25ff/common-java8-1.1.1.jar
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:306)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/lalit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/android.arch.lifecycle/common-java8/1.1.1/795d68cd761d093ccb235d1d91b8fd17c2ae25ff/common-java8-1.1.1.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:803)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$8(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:728)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:169)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:798)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:88)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:144)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:67)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:62)
    ... 10 more
    Suppressed: com.android.tools.r8.ApiLevelException: Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void android.arch.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver.onCreate(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.FileWriter.checkInterfaceMethod(FileWriter.java:247)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.FileWriter.checkInterfaceMethods(FileWriter.java:213)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.FileWriter.generate(FileWriter.java:140)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.writeDexFile(ApplicationWriter.java:356)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.lambda$write$2(ApplicationWriter.java:188)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709870/still-getting-warning-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462550/android-studio-build-gradle-warning-message

Comment: what about failed to resolve glide?

Comment: try `3.2.0` play-services !! instead of `3.1.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After two edits,,, finally I solved my problem by adding this

```
android{
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

and Gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    ext.roomVersion = '1.0.0'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Edit**

this helps me to solve my problem of ***TaskExecutionException***
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387435/2809351

Comment: This dependency is deprecated now  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade the version of kotlin "1.2.31"
add this dependencies in your app level gradle file :

> ```
> android {
>   ...
>
>   sourceSets {
>     main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
>   }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
> }
> ```

Don't forgot add plugin :

> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

Remove old dependency of jetbrains

> implementation
>   "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

It will helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening when you update the gradle or android studio to the latest version. Heres the fix for this problem.

Check your project gradle file. If there's `jcenter` in repositories, remove it and build the project.
The project gradle will look like :

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

}

If the error came again, after removing `jcenter()`, add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` inside the repositories and build again.

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue earlier but solved it.

Make sure under your (Project's) build.gradle, you have:

```
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

I have it in both repositories.

After adding that, I still had an error. If you do, comment out jcenter().

This is my build.gradle to make it work:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Let me know if it works too for you.

Comment: I just saw your edit, I"m not using Kotlin so I'm not sure if my answer will help solve your issue.  Other than the above, I also updated some SDK's: Tools > SDK Manager > Click on SDK Tools tab > I updated "Android SDK Build-Tools 28-rc1", Installed Google play services, and have both Android Support Repository and Google Repository checked.

Comment: Try to comment out each of your plug ins 1 by 1 and see if the error message changes?

Comment: Funny, I have to remove mavenCentral and use jcenter instead.